# How can I change the text color in ListView when a new file has been added or deleted in FileSystemWatcher?

Tags: c#, winforms

Is it possible to change the text color in `ListView` when a new file or folder has been added in `FileSystemWatcher`

So at the moment I have:

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    fileWatcher1.Items.Add(string.Format("File Deleted:  {0} File Name:  {1}", e.FullPath, e.Name));
}

private void fileSystemWatcher1_Renamed(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    fileWatcher1.Items.Add(string.Format("File Renamed:  {0} File Name:  {1}", e.FullPath, e.Name));
}

private void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    fileWatcher1.Items.Add(string.Format("File Created:  {0} File Name:  {1}", e.FullPath, e.Name));
}
```

What I would like to do is when a file has been created the color of the text should then be green and for Deleted it should be red and then if the file has been renamed it should be yellow.

Thanks

Comment: Find the item and change its `ForeColor`.

Comment: Hi thanks,  But how do I do that?